# How do you detect a URL being dragged from a browser into a WPF TextBox using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop

I have a WPF project written in C# intended to run on Windows 10.  I would like to be able to drag and drop the URL from a browser into a WPF TextBox and detect when the URL is dropped into the WPF TextBox.

I have been able to do this for files from the File Explorer but the same drag drop events I am using for files is not working for the dropping of the URL from the browser.  When I release the dragging button the URL text is copied into the WPF TextBox but I am not getting any event being raised when this happens related to a drag drop activity as I do when I am dropping a dragged file.

Below are the WPF events I am using for detecting drag and drop of files from File Explorer but am not getting Drag events for dropping URLs from a browser:

```
   private void InfoTextBox_DragOver(object sender, System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(System.Windows.DataFormats.FileDrop))
        e.Effects = System.Windows.DragDropEffects.Copy;
      else
        e.Effects = System.Windows.DragDropEffects.None;

      e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void InfoTextBox_DragEnter(object sender, System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(System.Windows.DataFormats.FileDrop))
        e.Effects = System.Windows.DragDropEffects.Copy;
      else
        e.Effects = System.Windows.DragDropEffects.None;

      e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void InfoTextBox_Drop(object sender, System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
    {
      string[] filenames = (string[])e.Data.GetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.FileDrop);


      InfoTextBox.Text = File.ReadAllText(filenames[0]);
    }
```

Below is the XAML for the TextBox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="InfoTextBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
         Grid.Row="5" Grid.RowSpan="7" 
         AllowDrop="True" PreviewDragOver="InfoTextBox_PreviewDragOver" 
         DragEnter="InfoTextBox_DragEnter" Drop="InfoTextBox_Drop"
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,0,-8,80" BorderBrush="PowderBlue"
         BorderThickness="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
         TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" 
         Text="" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" DragOver="InfoTextBox_DragOver"   />
```

What can I add to my WPF application so the InfoTextBox fires an event when I drop a URL from a browser onto it? I am getting the TextChanged event but that is not specific to a drag drop as it can also be fired just when someone types into the box which. As a last effort I may use the TextChanged event but would like to know if it can be done with something made for a drag drop operation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I replicated your issue. Something is handling the event when you drop text (which is what the URL from a browser is when dropped). You will have to use the Preview* events to catch it. In your XAML, change Drop to PreviewDrop and it should start firing.

Comment: Thank you J.H. adding preview drop fixed the problem.